# Android room persistence query is returning null value

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am currently learning how to utilize the Android Room Persistence library. The following code encounters an issue when attempting to query (findById) for a saved boolean value which is tied to an int (ID). When attempting to do so, it repeatedly comes up with null. Is there an issue here that I have neglected to notice? Could someone point me in the right direction on what I am doing incorrectly here? Thank you.

FavoriteMovieDao

```
@Dao
public interface FavoriteMovieDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM favoritemovie")
    List<FavoriteMovie> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favoritemovie WHERE id IN (:ids)")
    List<FavoriteMovie> loadAllByIds(int[] ids);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favoritemovie WHERE id LIKE :id LIMIT 1")
    FavoriteMovie findById(int id);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(FavoriteMovie movie);

    @Delete
    void delete(FavoriteMovie movie);
}
```

FavoriteMovie.java (entity)

```
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id){
    id = id;
}

@ColumnInfo(name = "favorite")
private boolean favorite;

public boolean getFavorite(){
    return favorite;
}

public void setFavorite(boolean favorite){
    favorite = favorite;
}

public void FavoriteMovie(int id, boolean favorite) {
    this.id = id;
    this.favorite = favorite;
}
```

Attempting to query, before performing insert

```
db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
AppDatabase.class, "database-name").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
if (db.favoriteMovieDao().findById(classId) == null) {
    FavoriteMovie fm = new FavoriteMovie();
    fm.setId(classId);
    fm.setFavorite(true);
    db.favoriteMovieDao().insert(fm);
}
```

AppDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = {FavoriteMovie.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract FavoriteMovieDao favoriteMovieDao();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setId` method does not reference the field `id`. Your parameter shadows your field. I think you should be using `this.id` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I completely overlooked that!